# A simple clarification on informatica mapping logic

Tags: oracle11g, data-warehouse, informatica-powercenter

I have to work on transformation
Can anyone help me on writing a query for the below transformation

```
Source Column name (from lookup) 
Source table        (local_usr_tbl)

Lookup_1:(rpt_user_tbl)

INPUT              CON_NUM,ML_SYMBL
MATCH CONDITION     NBR = CON_NUM AND SYMBL = ML_SYMBL1
Output              SYMBL

TRANSFORMATION LOGIC::

IIF(ISNULL(SYMBL), IIF(ISNULL(SYMBL1), ML_SYMBL1,  SYMBL1), SYMBL )

Target Column name     ML_SYMBL1(rpt_remote_table)
```

Please explain me how to make this transofrmation.I have all the other columns as direct move.Please help me out

Comment: @peter I am testing this.So I want to write a query.Thats why i asked this doubt.I want to convert this transformation logic to an equivalent query to perform datawarehouse testing

Comment: What do your tables look like? We can't help you without a better idea of your data model...

Answer (score 0):

This query might help you in testing :

```
select rpt_remote_table.ML_SYMBL1,local_usr_tbl.ML_SYMBL from local_usr_tbl, rpt_remote_table where local_usr_tbl.SYMBL is null and local_usr_tbl.SYMBL1 is null
```